# RavenDB - save or update entity, changed outside the session

Tags: ravendb

While getting familiar with RavenDb I've stumbled into one important question - is it possible to open session, load document, then close session, edit previously loaded document, open another session and update document in the database?

All examples provided in documentation demonstrates document's editing inside one single session only. Also I am aware about patch operations, but both scenarios does not fit my demands.

Maybe there is something resembling EF's SaveOrApdate() or another mechanism I don't know yet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No problem.
You can open a session, save a document & close the session.
After that, you can open another session, load the document that you saved, edit it, and save it again.

```
Company newCompany = new Company
{
    Name = companyName,
    Phone = companyPhone
};

// Open a session and save a new document
using (IDocumentSession session = DocumentStoreHolder.Store.OpenSession())
{
    session.Store(newCompany); 
    // The new document ID is immediately available, save it for later usage                  
    theNewDocumentId = newCompany.Id;                    
    session.SaveChanges();
}

// Open a session, Load the document, edit & save 
using (IDocumentSession session = DocumentStoreHolder.Store.OpenSession())
{
    Company company = session.Load<Company>(theNewDocumentId );                
    company.Name = companyName;                
    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

See explanation about **the new document ID that is generated** in:
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/basics/create-document#step-3

Comment: Well, this is the same scenario which I've described - editing take place INSIDE session. My goal - to modify object, associated with a document OUTSIDE the session.

Comment: You can use a ```Put Command``` to insert or update a document in the database without using the Session at all.
See https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/csharp/client-api/commands/documents/put

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `Session`? You can use as many as you need. Each session represents a business transaction and tracks your changes until you call `SaveChanges()` which persists the data to the database.

Comment: Because common scenario looks like this: web application load documents from DB and then send it to client over the network. Then client can modify one of the documents and then send it back to server to update this document in DB. it is impossible to do this with one session, because load and update operations are represented by two different methods. Put Command really looks like reasonable solution, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Danielle a use case for not doing it inside of a sessions is that the entity gets returned to another class that makes changes and then calls `SavesChanges` on the class holding the session. Like an abstracted unit of work repository